# Python crawl table elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract from this webpage(http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/CHO/2017.html) all of the elements corresponding to table (Team Misc).

I would like to extract all the numbers from "Team" - (this line:
17  13  2.17    -0.51   1.66    106.9   104.7   96.5    .300    .319    .493    10.9    20.5    .228    .501    11.6    79.6    .148    Spectrum Center 269,47)

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmla = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/CHO/2017.html')
bsObja=BeautifulSoup(htmla,"html.parser")
tables = bsObja.find_all("table")
```

Tried the above code, hoping that I will get a list of all tables and then choose the right one. But now matter how I try, I only get 1 table from this page.

Any Ideas on another approach ?

Comment: Please include that picture directly in your question instead of a link that might be broken at any time.

Comment: this page has all data in HTML but hidden as comments and uses JavaScript to show it. But you can use `BeautifuSoup` to find this comments, remove `<!--` and `-->` and use result with `BeautifuSoup` to get data. I think this problem was solved in some question before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page has all tables hidden in comments and JavaScript uses it to display table and probably to sort or filter before display.

All comments are after `<div class='placeholder'>` so you can use this to find this comments, get all text from comment and use BS to parse it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'http://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/CHO/2017.html'

#html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = requests.get(url).text

soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')

placeholders = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'placeholder'})

total_tables = 0

for x in placeholders:
    # get elements after placeholder and join in one string
    comment = ''.join(x.next_siblings)

    # parse comment
    soup_comment = BS(comment, 'html.parser')

    # search table in comment
    tables = soup_comment.find_all('table')

    # ... do something with table ...

    #print(tables)

    total_tables += len(tables)

print('total tables:', total_tables)
```

This way I found 11 tables hidden in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
tables = bsObja.findAll("table")
```

Comment: Still, I get only 1 table :(

Comment: I've just looked at the page.  It is because the tables are being loaded by JavaScript.  You need to use Selenium

Comment: Ok. I will have a look and see how it works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: yes, the page is rendered by JS, but the table code is written in the html code.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the Comment object in the BS, and the Comment object is just a special type of NavigableString, what you need to do are:

1. Find the sting that contain the information
2. Use BeautifulSoup convert the string to BS object
3. Extract data from BS object

**Code:**

```
import re
table_string = soup.find(string=re.compile('div_team_misc'))
```

This will return the sting that contains table html code.

```
table = BeautifulSoup(table_string, 'lxml')
```

Use the sting to construct BS object, and extract data from the object

```
for tr in table.find_all('tr', class_=False):
    s = [td.string for td in tr('td')]
    print(s)
```

**Out:**

```
['17', '13', '2.17', '-0.51', '1.66', '106.9', '104.7', '96.5', '.300', '.319', '.493', '10.9', '20.5', '.228', '.501', '11.6', '79.6', '.148', 'Spectrum Center', '269,471']
['10', '9', '8', '24', '10', '17', '5', '15', '4', '11', '22', '1', '27', '5', '12', '28', '3', '1', None, '15']
```

**More about comment:**

```
markup = "<b><!--Hey, buddy. Want to buy a used parser?--></b>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
comment = soup.b.string
```

The Comment object is just a special type of NavigableString, BS will extract the string from , We do not need to change or replace any html.

```
comment
# u'Hey, buddy. Want to buy a used parser'
```

Based on this, we can use pure BS instead of `re` to extract comment

```
table_string = soup.find(id="all_team_misc").contents[-2]
```

If you what to find all the table strings, you can do this:

```
from bs4 import Commnet
tables = soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment) and str(text).startswith('  \n'))
```